# IMDbPY get the stars of a movie

Tags: python, movie, imdb, imdbpy

I was able to get the cast of the movie like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import imdb
ia = imdb.IMDb()
s_result = ia.search_movie('The Untouchables')
the_unt = s_result[0]
print the_unt['cast']
```

However, that gave all the *cast*, i am looking for just the *stars* of the movie. for example, al pacino is a star in god father

Comment: Did you look at the other attributes of `the_unt`? Do you actually know if IMDb exposes that information?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i look of course, indeed i printed it all but i didn't see stars or related attribute. `print the_unt.items()`

Comment: In the terms of movies, cast members are effectively the stars.  Even Al Pacino had to start in some obscure film.

Comment: @Makoto sorry but i am asking about the *stars* not *starts*

Comment: Then evidently the API doesn't expose it. Is that information in the *order* of the cast? Is it actually available in IMDb? Have you tried to implement it yourself? Do you have an answerable, SO-appropriate question?

Comment: You seem to be missing my point.  Every actor that became a big, household name eventually had to start at *some* point.  I'm not certain that IMDB would be able to expose this kind of information since, depending on the movie you're looking for, that specific actor may *not* have been a "star" by your definition.  What I'm saying is that what you're searching for in your data set may be trickier to accomplish than just asking the API.

Comment: I could go on...Macaulay Culkin was a star  in the late 80s and early 90s, but I'd be hesitant to consider him one now.  He was cast in several movies, though, so that information is easy enough to expose.  My concern is that you may be conflating a role in a movie, which the API is equipped for, with someone that's *famous* for their roles in movies, which the API may *not* be equipped for.

Comment: Following along with your code, I get a KeyError at `'cast'`... At least from [this IMDbPy](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Comment: @Makoto you are not getting me my friend, i didn't mean star in general, but i mean the star in that movie, it is like the main character or the movie. example, al pinion is a star in god father. got me please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, IMDb does not know the concept of a "star", but it does somewhat know the "top actors" from the cast lineup.

It is probably based on the credits of the film, but even IMDb says *first billed only* for some movies.

The cast ordering is entirely dependent on the movie and who verifies the data on IMDb. If it says "credits order", that means "in the order they were introduced in the film credits", **but**, the credit ordering could be some arbitrary ordering that the director of the film felt like placing them in.

For example, some films say "And introducing... (some actor no one knows about)" or like a TV Show says "Special Guest Star... (someone most people recognize)". In both cases, those are either before / after the entire regular cast is introduced.

---

So, if you wanted the top 5 actors for a given film, you could do something like this

```
import imdb
ia = imdb.IMDb()
search_results = ia.search_movie('The Godfather')

if search_results:
     movieID = search_results[0].movieID
     movie = ia.get_movie(movieID)
     if movie:
         cast = movie.get('cast')
         topActors = 5
         for actor in cast[:topActors]:
             print "{0} as {1}".format(actor['name'], actor.currentRole)
```

Output

```
Marlon Brando as Don Vito Corleone
Al Pacino as Michael Corleone
James Caan as Sonny Corleone
Richard S. Castellano as Clemenza
Robert Duvall as Tom Hagen
```

Comment: what is topActors? variable ?

Comment: It is an integer. It is clearly declared in the code

Comment: after your update, i see, how did you know that the actors are arranged according to their importance ?

Comment: I don't, and neither does IMDb. You are scraping a website, and the best you are going to get is the order they appear on the site.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Some movies, for example, might list the cast in order that they appear in the film.

Comment: look http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm it is written **in credits order** is that a good indicator that they are in the star order please ?

Comment: In the hovertext of the arrow. *Question shows no research effort*. For example, from reading your question to the time I posted, I never have used this API, so the resources and documentation were definitely available to you in order to get the same answer I provided.